# InterruptedException; must be caught or declared to be thrown

Tags: java, exception, thread-sleep, java-threads

I keep getting the following error:

```
 PrintServerV1.java:63: error: unreported exception InterruptedException; must be caught or declared to be thrown
        server.printRequest("homework7.txt");
                           ^
PrintServerV1.java:64: error: unreported exception InterruptedException; must be caught or declared to be thrown
        server.printRequest("assignment4.txt");
                           ^
PrintServerV1.java:65: error: unreported exception InterruptedException; must be caught or declared to be thrown
        server.printRequest("speech.pdf");
```

And I am pretty sure that I have thrown the error. This error only happens when add the following line: `Thread.sleep(1000)`
Here is my code:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.util.concurrent.locks.Lock;
import java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock;
import java.util.concurrent.locks.Condition;

import static java.lang.System.out;

public class PrintServerV1 implements Runnable {

    private static final Queue<String> requests = new LinkedList<String>();
    private Lock lock = new ReentrantLock();
    private Condition condition = lock.newCondition();

    public void printRequest(String s)  throws InterruptedException   {
        lock.lock();
        try {
            out.println("Adding print request for: " + s);
            requests.add(s);
            condition.signal();
        } finally { lock.unlock(); Thread.sleep(1000);}


    }

    public void sendRequest() throws InterruptedException {
        lock.lock();
        try {
            while (requests.size() == 0) {
                condition.await();
            }
            out.println("Sending Request to printer");
            Thread.sleep(1000);
            while (!requests.isEmpty()) {
                realPrint(requests.remove());
            }
        } finally {
            lock.unlock();
        }
    }

    private void realPrint(String s) throws InterruptedException  {
        // do the real work of outputting the string to the screen
        out.println("Currently printing: " + s);
        Thread.sleep(1000);
    }

    public void run() {
        try {
            sendRequest();
        } catch (InterruptedException exception) {}
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        PrintServerV1 server = new PrintServerV1();
        new Thread(server).start();
        server.printRequest("homework7.txt");
        server.printRequest("assignment4.txt");
        server.printRequest("speech.pdf");
    }
}
```

Comment: Those are _compiler_ errors, not runtime errors.  No exception has been thrown, as the program cannot actually be executed.  It is telling you that your `printRequest` is declared to throw `InterruptedException` but you are not catching it in the code that calls `printRequest`.

Comment: This is well explained in any introduction to exceptions tutorial. Please have a look at [this one](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/)

Answer (score 1):

Because your printRequest method throws an InterruptedException, it must be caught in main, or thrown by main... either one of the following answers ought to work ...

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    PrintServerV1 server = new PrintServerV1();
    new Thread(server).start();
    server.printRequest("homework7.txt");       // these throw an exception
    server.printRequest("assignment4.txt");     // That is "InterruptedException"
    server.printRequest("speech.pdf");          // It must be caught, or declared thrown!
                                                // Version 1 declares it thrown (above in method declaration)
}


public static void main(String[] args) {
    PrintServerV1 server = new PrintServerV1();
    try {
        new Thread(server).start();
        server.printRequest("homework7.txt");
        server.printRequest("assignment4.txt");
        server.printRequest("speech.pdf");
    catch (InterruptedException e) { e.printStackTrace(); } // Version 2 catches it
}
```